# Modelling the fluidity of a fluid (grease) based on temperature

Tags: fluid-dynamics, temperature

I am trying to create a statistical model of a lubrication system. A central grease pump takes grease from a tank and injects it into some cavities (via grease lines) until a pressure set-point is reached.
I noticed that the system takes longer to pump grease through all the lines when the temperature is colder. I assume this is because the grease's fluidity reduces in cold temperature, therefore it travels slower through the lines and is pumped less efficiently.

Back to my statistical model: I am trying to do a regression to correlate temperature records with observations of the time required to lubricate all parts. I am wondering which regression model I should use:

- a linear function `time = a + b x temperature` doesn't work well.
- a second-order polynomial fits the data quite well
- a log `time = a+ b x log(temperature)` fits the data quite well too

Can you give me an insight in the underlying science behind my observations? I assume there are a lot of other factors, such as pressure, velocity of the fluid inside the lines, type of lines, diameter, etc...
But for a start, which law determines the fluidity of a lubricant like grease, based on temperature ? For instance, is it a polynomial, an exponential, 1/x, or something else ?

**EDIT**

I just stumbled upon this: [Wikipedia Temperature dependence of liquid viscosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_dependence_of_liquid_viscosity).
I guess Grease is not exactly a fluid, but all these laws seem to be exponential or log.

Comment: Define "fits the data quite well." Is it "chi-by-eye" (*looks* like a fit) or did you do a [chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test)?

Comment: Chi-by-eye.
I'm hoping to get some suggestions from experts on what might be the underlying model of my system before I start investigating further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Viscosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity) is the material's resistance to shearing stress. According to the Wikipedia entry, [water has a viscosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Viscosity_of_selected_substances) that is exponential:
$$
\mu\sim A\cdot10^{B/(T-C)}
$$
If we then look at the Navier-Stokes equations (which holds for Newtonian fluids, something grease is not (instead a [non-Newtonian fluid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid))),
$$
\rho\left(\color{blue}{\frac{\partial\mathbf v}{\partial t}}+\mathbf v\cdot\nabla\mathbf v\right)=-\nabla p+\color{blue}{\mu\nabla^2\mathbf v}+\mathbf f,
$$
where $\rho$ is the mass-density, $\mathbf v$ the fluid velocity, $p$ the fluid pressure, and $\mathbf f$ other forces involved (e.g., gravity), the highlighted colors suggest a linear relation between viscosity and time might be a good start. The fact that grease is non-Newtonian would change the relation between $t$ and $\mu$, however, since it appears to be the case that $\mu$ is non-linearly dependent on temperature, a logarithmic relation between $t$ and $\mu$ might be the direction to take.

I would suggest looking at the [chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) of both the polynomial fit and the exponential fit. Note that free software like R and Python do have some built-in chi-squared algorithms (though the Python [requires SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.chisquare.html))--I presume also other for-pay software also have this feature, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: It's worth noting that what you have there is the Navier-Stokes equations for a Newtonian fluid. According to the examples on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_fluid#Examples), water, air and thin motor oil are all close enough to Newtonian. But depending on the applications, grease/oil may be non-Newtonian. Asking my favorite search engine ["is grease non-Newtonian"](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+grease+non-newtonian) seems to indicate that it is non-Newtonian.

Comment: @tpg2114: A thought I hadn't considered, one that would certainly change the linearity between $t$ and $\mu$. At least my answer could provide a starting point, even if not entirely correct.